# Automatic language translation of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code here on stackoverflow

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Google translate</title>
  <style>
    .skiptranslate,
    #google_translate_element {
      display: none;
    }
    
    body {
      min-height: 0px !important;
      position: static !important;
      top: 0px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>

<body>
  The text is translated using Google translate.
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      $.when(
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'en',
          includedLanguages: 'es',
          layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT
        }, 'google_translate_element')
      ).done(function() {
        var select = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo')[0];
        select.selectedIndex = 1;
        select.addEventListener('click', function() {
          select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        });
        select.click();
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

I want to ask that how can I automatically translate the webpage to a specific language when loaded. The above code does not work. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question works (with some extra remarks below), provided that you take the following snippet out of the code:

```
<style>
    .skiptranslate, #google_translate_element {display: none;}
    body {min-height: 0px !important; position: static !important; top: 0px !important;}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6L75dor/ This produces the following result:

[image: Works]

It did however fail sometimes because I got warnings about Cross-Origin Read Blocking in the Chrome Dev tools:

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0jtsqm3f5 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

So you might have to look into that more thoroughly before using in a production environment.
Also, sometimes it ran automatically, and sometimes it only worked after I clicked the dropdown manually (notice that in the code it attaches a click handler to the dropdown list), so this may be related to loading times or something, but again, this might be something worth looking into as well.

Comment: Actually I dont want to show the languages list on the page. So thats why the style code is there. This should be automatic translation of the page to given language like spanish in the code.